# Loading predefined .zpl file to Zebra printer's settings from code

Tags: zebra-printers

I'm using Zebra ZD220 and I'm looking for a way to configure some of the printer's properties from my code. I have been thinking about loading .zpl file that has all the commands I need but I couldn't solve it just yet.
The code is in C#.
Please help me to figure it out.

Comment: Your q is to vague. Sure you can send ZPL commands to the printer, it doesn't matter where they come from. What matters is how is the printer connected!? This leads to different APIs you can use to send the commands. By the way, there should be some C# libs for ZPL around, have you searched the internet already?

Comment: The printer is connected with usb cable to my computer. 
There are several C# libs but, with one of them I have managed to change some of the printer's settings temporarily. Every time that I printed something or disconnected the printer the settings returned to their old statement. I thought about loading .zpl file instead of changing the settings with SGD functions because it looks shorter and more readable.
My biggest problem is that no matter what I'm doing, every new printing resets the settings that I'm trying to modify.

Comment: Have you tried to change the default settings of the printer in the Windows printer settings?

Comment: I have tried it manually (from the printer's preferences) and it works but I need to figure out a way to change the settings from my code

Comment: We print ZPL files that always contain settings commands, we don't rely on the settings of the printer itself. Do you have trouble finding the correct ZPL replacement commands for the SGD commands you used so far?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have found some SGD commands that should work but as I said, when I'm using those SGD commands, at first it works (Get commands show that Set commands worked) and than a printing operation ignores those changes and uses the default settings.